# Ubuntu 23.04 installation fails with subiquity errors

Tags: system-installation, 23.04

I want to install Ubuntu 23.04 on my system but I encounter this error:

```
Apr 27 14:27:14 ubuntu subiquity_event.3285[3285]: subiquity/Early/apply_autoinstall_config
Apr 27 14:27:14 ubuntu subiquity_event.3285[3285]: subiquity/Early/apply_autoinstall_config
Apr 27 14:27:14 ubuntu subiquity_event.3285[3285]: subiquity/Reporting/apply_autoinstall_config
Apr 27 14:27:14 ubuntu subiquity_event.3285[3285]: subiquity/Reporting/apply_autoinstall_config
Apr 27 14:27:14 ubuntu subiquity_event.3285[3285]: subiquity/Error/apply_autoinstall_config
Apr 27 14:27:14 ubuntu subiquity_event.3285[3285]: subiquity/Error/apply_autoinstall_config
Apr 27 14:27:14 ubuntu subiquity_event.3285[3285]: subiquity/Userdata/apply_autoinstall_config
Apr 27 14:27:14 ubuntu subiquity_event.3285[3285]: subiquity/Userdata/apply_autoinstall_config
Apr 27 14:27:14 ubuntu subiquity_event.3285[3285]: subiquity/Package/apply_autoinstall_config
Apr 27 14:27:14 ubuntu subiquity_event.3285[3285]: subiquity/Package/apply_autoinstall_config
Apr 27 14:27:14 ubuntu subiquity_event.3285[3285]: subiquity/Debconf/apply_autoinstall_config
Apr 27 14:27:14 ubuntu subiquity_event.3285[3285]: subiquity/Debconf/apply_autoinstall_config
Apr 27 14:27:14 ubuntu subiquity_event.3285[3285]: subiquity/Kernel/apply_autoinstall_config
Apr 27 14:27:14 ubuntu subiquity_event.3285[3285]: subiquity/Kernel/apply_autoinstall_config
```

[image: screenshot of installation errors]

Answer (score 1):

It's May 2023 and I have this same problem. The only way I've gotten around this issue is to not put /home on a separate partition.

Comment: Doesn't work even without Home/Swap partitions and Safe Mode (to eliminate NVIDIA issues).

Answer (score 0):

Test the file you downloaded for download errors (look at the sha256 number as explained here : https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview). If it is not the one it should be, download the installation file again. If it is the correct sha256 number, just try the installation again.

Comment: I downloaded the file from the official Ubuntu website, I did it again, but my problem was not solved, when I run the installation screen, it flashes and then it is deleted, I installed it on another system, but there was no problem, my monitor is 32 inches, RAM 24 Core 7 I